# Is past perfect ok for a specific event

Tags: past-tense

He said that no steam train 13)....has/had passed...(pass) through that station for years, and that thelast one 14).....**had crashed.**..(crash), killing everyone on board.

I am just wondering if instead of had crashed  **crashed** would be ok as the last one refers to a specific train as in the expression  the last time I went to Paris. I know past perfect is better as it happened a long timr before the verb in past simple said but....

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/112456062/10-Texts-to-Revise-Mixed-Tenses-With-Key

Answer (score 1):

It should be "had crashed" because it's reported speech. The speech reported is in past tense ("He said"), so what he said has to be in past perfect tense.
 See:
[EF.edu tense changes in reported speech](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/)